# Find revision when particular test started failing

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, tfsbuild

We are in a situation when developers broken the TDD process and stopped running tests few weeks ago, and now we have about 25 failing tests in solution.

Also i we do not have build archives for failed builds, because a nightly build definition was not set up to keep failed bilds in TFS

What would be your approach to this problem?

Is it possible to queue a range of revisions to build in TFS?
I can't even find a way to queue one particular revision.

In a perfect world, given a range of revisions, i would like to be able to run some automatic procedure against TFS and get the report - at which revision number each test started failing.

Answer (score 1):

You may use logarithmic search. Hit the middle. Good? Go right. Not good? Go left.

Comment: nice idea. but I think you mean interval nesting instead logarithmic search.
More details for george: assume you are at revision 4:

1. svn up -r 2
2. build
3. if failed => "svn up -r 1" else if
   success => "svn up -r 3"

Comment: That's what i'm currently doing, thanks. But having 100+ revisions and different tests failing at different revisions it does not seem a logarithmic task. Also reverting, deploying and running tests takes about 40 min. for each revision.

Answer (score 0):

After googling on the subject i came across this article:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=342

At least i can now queue a range of revisions to build.